# Substitute for `array[:,*idx]` in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

Let

```
a = np.ones([3]*4)
```

It's not possible to replace

```
a[:,2,1,0] = 1
```

by

```
idx = [2,1,0]
a[:,*idx] = 1
```

Are there alternatives? I need this because I am looping over all `idx` in `{0,1,...,m}^n` (`m=2`, `n=3` in my example) with `m` and `n` variable.

Comment: In your actual use-case is `idx` a 2D array? Can you show a sample of idx keeping the number of dimensions of it the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `slice(None)` to represent `:` and "fill" your `idx` array

```
mask = (slice(None),)*(len(a.shape) - len(idx)) + tuple(idx)

b[mask] = 0
```

The idea is to instead of doing the intuitive `a[:, *idx]` which would mean `a[:,2,1,0]`, you'd do `a[[:,2,1,0]]` by filling your `idx` with `:` to its left

Or if you want to hard-code it ;)

```
b[(slice(None),*idx)] = 0
```

Comment: So `a[[slice(None),*idx]]` is the direct substitute. Great!

Comment: @PaulPanzer yea, gotta use `tuples` to avoid the deprecation. I'll edit

Answer (score 2):

You can do almost what you tried like so:

```
a[(...,*idx)] = 1
```

Comment: Nice use of ellipsis ;)